# How to use chromedriver to test Chrome on Android

Tags: c#, android, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, remotewebdriver

in my infrastructure, I have Selenium Hub and Selenium nodes connected to this Hub. I have nodes for each desktop browser I need to test. To run a test in my grid on let's say Chrome, I start the chromedriver with the following parameters:

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://myseleniumhubip:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=chrome,platform=WINDOWS -port 5557
```

And I create my driver in the test like this:

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();            
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://myseleniumhubip:4444/wd/hub"), capability);
```

And everything works as expected. Browser is launched on remote machine and test performs.

However, I would also like to test in Chrome on my real Android device. Problem is, I have no idea how to start chromedriver (what parameters to use), nor how to create RemoteWebDriver to accomplish this.

Could anyone please help me?

- I have Android SDK installed on the machine with chromedriver
- Phone is set into debugging mode
- I'm using C# for my tests

Thank you!

Comment: You should start `adb-server` along with `chromedriver-server`, so execute `adb start-server` in `cmd` and add `{  'chromeOptions': {    'androidPackage': 'com.android.chrome'  } }` to `capability`

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's still struggling with this, the following approach works fine for me:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("androidPackage", "com.android.chrome");

driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://myseleniumhubip:4444/wd/hub"), chromeOptions.ToCapabilities());
```